# jsonRpcService in addOnLoad

Tags: xpages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">   
<xe:jsonRpcService
    id="jsonRpcService1"
    serviceName="rpcService">
    <xe:this.methods>
        <xe:remoteMethod
            name="machwas"
            script="MyBean.machwas() ;">
        </xe:remoteMethod>
    </xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
console.log( rpcService ) ;}) ;]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
setTimeout( function(){ 
    console.log( rpcService ) ; 
}, 1 );});]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

This code throws an Error in scriptBlock1:

```
test.xsp:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: rpcService is not defined
at test.xsp:21
at _55c (dojo.js:15)
at $DDUS_ (dojo.js:15)
at $DDUT_ (dojo.js:15)
at $DDUR_ (dojo.js:15)
at HTMLDocument.$DDHs_ (dojo.js:15)
```

scriptBlock2 works.

I wonder about that because I use it like in scriptBlock1 in other, more complex xpages. But can not find the reason why it's working there and not in the simple code above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with XSP.addOnLoad() instead of dojo.addOnLoad()

Comment: No difference with XSP.addOnLoad().

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `xe:jsonRPCService` is outputting a script in the global `XSP.addOnLoad` code block for your whole page. This script get outputted in the bottom of your page and will be evaluated / run by your browser after the whole page is loaded.

But a `xp:script` block will output a new stand alone `<script>` tag before that global block was executed, so the variable `rpcService` was not created yet at that point. Using a setTimeout function will make sure your script runs a little bit later, but depending on the browser/speed I wouldn't really count on it.

Instead of using a scriptblock you could try to use the SSJS `view.postScript` function to add your script in the global load scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanaition.
Where / how to implement view.postScript? Did'n use it yet. Any examples?

Comment: view.postScript is SSJS code. Inside the postScript() method you could call Javascript (for the browser). But also, this method adds the javascript in the bottom of the page that will fix your problem. Check here for some example of how to use it, https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=display-client-side-alert-if-server-side-validation-fails